# Obtaining UITableViewCell selection status within tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the height of a `UITableViewCell` when it's selected because I'm using different `cellPrototypes` for selected and non-selected cells.
The cells are in a `UITableView` which is embedded in an `UIView`, which is the TableView's delegate and datasource.
But when I try to check whether the cell at `indexPath` is selected, I am apparently producing an infinite recursion.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat cellHeight = 64;
    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].selected) {
        cellHeight = 128;
    return cellHeight;
}
```

Could you help me finding a working solution, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'r doing is wrong, because you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which cause the tableView to call `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, so you have the infinite recursion.

The best option to achieve what you want is by having an object to save the index path of the selected cell to make it wider

1) first have a global variable call it `NSIndexPath currentSelectedCellIndex` 
2) in `cellDidSelectCellAtIndexPath` change the variable and reload the cell as follows

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     currentSelectedCellIndex = indexPath;
     [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

3) finally in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` return the new height for the selected cell

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      if(indexPath.row == currentSelectedCellIndex.row) {
         // for example 60
         return 60;
       }
       return 44;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to my first solution but I wanted to try if it works without the global variable. Anyway, then I stick to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the tableView on didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.